# How to find the canonical equations of the RLC circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

First, I consider the LC circuit with an ion in the capacitor, which is like this:

[image]

The current $I$ can be derived easily by using Shockly-Ramo theorem
\begin{equation}
 I = -\frac{qp}{dM} + C\dot{U} \ \ \ (1)
 \end{equation}
where $q$ is the charge and $M$ is the mass of the particle, $p = M\dot{z}$ is the momentum of the particle, $d$ is the separation of the two plates, $C$ is the capacitance and $U$ is the voltage across the capacitor. By taking the circuit-charge $Q$ on the capacitor as the generalized coordinate and the magnetic flux through the inductor $\Phi = L\dot{Q}$($L$ is the inductance of the inductor) as the momentum, it is easy to derive the canonical equations of the circuit with Kirchhoff's law $U = -\dot{\Phi}$.
\begin{equation}
 \dot{Q} = \frac{\Phi}{L}\ \ \ (2)
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \dot{\Phi} = -\frac{Q}{C} - \frac{qz}{Cd}\ \ \ (3)
 \end{equation}

Now we consider the series RLC circuit case.

My question is that how to find the canonical equations of the series RLC circuit with the same canonical coordinates(which is $Q$ and $\Phi$)? [In the third page of this paper](https://sci.bban.top/pdf/10.1088/2058-9565%252Faaf5f3.pdf?download=true), it says that there will be two more terms added in equation(3), $-\Gamma\Phi$ and $\sqrt{2\Gamma L k_BT}\xi(t)$, where $\Gamma = \frac{R}{L}$. So the first term is the damping term and the other term, according to that paper, should be the thermal noise of the resister. I just can not find the correct canonical equations that satisfies the result in the paper.

Comment: I can't answer other questions but $\sqrt{2R k_BT}\xi(t)$ should be resistor's thermal noise, where $k_B$ is Boltzmann constant, $T$ is Kalvin temperature, and $\xi(t)$ is a stochastic process modeling the noise.

Comment: @verdelite can you offer more details? How to derive the thermal noise of that resistor?

Comment: Search for Johnson noise. Elements such as resistors can accumulate charge on their surface and their terminals due to thermal fluctuations inside and thus create their own voltage, whether macroscopic current is flowing through them or not.

Comment: @JánLalinský thanks, I will search that. Is it the same expression of the term $-qpR/dM$? I got this extra term in my equation(5).

Comment: @Hou I did not read the paper. The Johnson noise in the resistor $R$ is the reason for the term $\sqrt{2Rk_BT}\xi{t}$. The term $-qpR/M$ seems to be a different thing, due to charged particle between the capacitor plates.

Comment: @JánLalinský you mean the first term in equation(1)? That’s the current induced by the motion of ion, don’t let that bother you

Comment: @JánLalinský I have changed the question, if you haven’t noticed. Now I just want to find the correct canonical equations for the series RLC circuit....

Comment: @JánLalinský I searched something about the Johnson noise and find that the voltage noise density(per Hertz) is $\sqrt{4k_BTR}$, so what is $\xi (t)$? is it the bandwidth?

Comment: No, $\xi(t)$ is randomly oscillating function that describes the noise in time.

Comment: @JánLalinský oh...so what is the unit of $\xi(t)$? And why the noise here is $\sqrt{2k_BTR}$ not $\sqrt{4k_BTR}$ ? I know the unit of this whole term should be volt