# How to find the canonical equations of the series RLC circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, inductance

First, I consider the LC circuit with an ion in the capacitor, which is like this:

[image]

The current $I$ can be derived easily using Shockly-Ramo theorem
\begin{equation}
 I = -\frac{qp}{dM} + C\dot{U} \ \ \ (1)
 \end{equation}
where $q$ is the charge and $M$ is the mass of the particle, $p = M\dot{z}$ is the momentum of the particle, $d$ is the separation of the two plates, $C$ is the capacitance and $U$ is the voltage across the capacitor. By taking the circuit-charge $Q$ on the capacitor as the generalized coordinate and the magnetic flux through the inductor $\Phi = L\dot{Q}$($L$ is the inductance of the inductor) as the momentum, it is easy to derive the canonical equations of the circuit with Kirchhoff's law $U = -\dot{\Phi}$.
\begin{equation}
 \dot{Q} = \frac{\Phi}{L}\ \ \ (2)
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \dot{\Phi} = -\frac{Q}{C} - \frac{qz}{Cd}\ \ \ (3)
 \end{equation}

Now we consider the series RLC circuit case.

My question is that how to find the canonical equations of the series RLC circuit with the same canonical coordinates(which is $Q$ and $\Phi$)? [In the third page of this paper](https://sci.bban.top/pdf/10.1088/2058-9565%252Faaf5f3.pdf?download=true)it says that there will be two more terms added in equation(3), $-\Gamma\Phi$ and $\sqrt{2\Gamma L k_BT}\xi(t)$, where $\Gamma = \frac{R}{L}$. So the first term is the damping term and the other term, according to that paper, should be the thermal noise of the resister. I just can not find the correct canonical equations that satisfies the result in the paper.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/621507/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic maybe you are referring to another question that also asked by me days ago? I have deleted that question because I made some mistakes in that question......Anyway, the question I want to ask is this question....

Comment: Hi Hou. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, I will pay attention next time